# Base64 timeout for large file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, timeout, base64, encode

I'm trying to encode a ~40MB file with Base64.encode64 and write it's encoded string back into another file for the lulz.
Get a timeout from my browser when I try that out though. I'm pretty sure the code is correct (also it's not beautiful, but I started using Ruby 3 days ago...)
Is there any way I can set up the timeout limits?

```
def foo

  code = File.new("base64code.xml", "wb")
  original = File.open("asdf.exe", "rb")
  code << Base64.encode64(original.read)
  original.close
  code.close

end
```

Comment: Try it in console first.

Comment: wouldn't help me with what I wanna do next:
I wanted to try and add it to a XML file with gem Builder to see if I can fit it in there.
also I wanted to compare the time consumption of base64 encoding in a rails application for a thesis (with the likely outcome that it's outright stupid to encode bigger files just to include them into xml)